# Unity 2D - How does velocity and bouncy physic material causes the ball to change direction everytime it hits something?

Tags: unity-game-engine, bounce, pong

So, I'm following a youtube tutorial on how to make pong. I understand and learned alot of stuff but there's a point where he made the ball and its movement but he didn't explain it. He used

```c#
void Start() 
{
    rb.velocty = new Vector2(speed, speed);
}
```

The ball is also attached with a rigidbody2d, a circle collider with a physic material attached. The physic material has a friction of 0 and bounciness to 1. This somehow made the ball bounce off an object.

Can anyone explain to me how it works?

Thanks alot!

Comment: If you meant to ask how does ball change its direction, this behaviour is handled by [Physics Engine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PhysicsSection.html) on Unity. [Gravity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics-gravity.html) also handled by this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The line

  ```
  rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed, speed);
  ```

  simply sets the initial [velocity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-velocity.html) of the object in `x` and `y` direction.

  Since they use `x = y = speed` in the vector definition the ball will move diagonal in a 45° angle.

  Change those values in order to get different angle or speed.

See [Physic Materials](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html):

- `friction = 0` means that the object will not slow down. A value bigger than `0` would slow down the object over time.
- `bounciness 1` means that on collision the object won't loose any speed but instead bounce back with 100% of its velocity at the according angle. -> This is the part changing the direction of the object according to its impact angle etc

This is all handled by Unity's [PhysicsEngine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PhysicsSection.html) itself so you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Explained me alot. But can you explain me why velocity does that? For example, a ball floating in the sky with no gravityScale and on "Start", we add a velocity of (0, -5). When we hit play, the ball will fall and touch the ground then, bounces off in the opposite direction instead of doing a rotation of 90 degrees. Can you explain me why this example, it bounces off the opposite direction whereas my question bounces and rotates 90 degrees?

Comment: The difference is that if one of the two velocity axis is set to `0` it hits a flat surface with impact angle `90°` .. as you surely know from natural physics and the [reflection law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(physics)) `incoming angle = outgoing angle`. The same happens if you let a ball drop in nature exactly streight down => it comes back streight up. In the example however the angle was `45°` as mentioned so the ball bounces of on a reflected movement vector which is `-45°` on the surface => the difference in that case is `90°`

Comment: I'm terrible with physics but you explained it all. Thank you!